# SQL - phpMyAdmin: Import Excel gives invalid column count

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin to manage an SQL database and I am trying to import an excel file as a table. The file is saved as .csv. When I import the file an error pops up saying the is an invalid column count on one of the rows. The file contains close to 43.000 rows, so manually evaluating and changing each is impossible. At first sight I can't see the difference between the rows that give an error and those that don't. What could be is that there are special characters that maybe cause the error. Each row contains a description column and these exist in many different languages (also Arabic and Chinese).

Anybody any suggestions on how to get around this problem. I tried uploading it as an Opensheet file but that did not workout.

EDIT:

So I checked the rows that gave an error. There are some weird characters like "‡" but these come back in other rows as well that did not give an error.

Comment: This might be an issue with character encoding on your mysql server. In PHPmyadmin, try updating the charset of the database to utf8-general-ci

Comment: If you have a column count difference issue that means that the column separator character appears in some field data, usually in a longer text. You should export your data from excel to csv with text fields being encapsulated by `"` characters and use this setting in the import as well. This way the extra delimiter characters will not be interpreted by MySQL as field separators.

Comment: Hi, I'll give that a shot. I can also put it on utf16; not sure if that makes a difference?

Comment: @Shadow I'll also try this. Thanks!

Comment: @Shadow Hey I have been trying some things but haven't worked it out yet. Am I suppose to put the quotes around all values, or only the ones that differ per row and that could include one of the delimiters (e.g. title, description)? If I only put it the " those two columns, the csv files turns it into three "..

Comment: @Shadow Also, I just found out that for some reason some of the values in the column "description" get quotes around it when converted to csv, but others do not. Thought maybe that could indicate something?